# Google like autosuggest with Solr

Tags: autocomplete, solr, autosuggest

I'm currently using Solr with Terms Component and Jquery Autosuggest which works quiet good. However, this construct is limited to one autosuggest word (it autocompletes only the first word). Is it possible to implement a Google like autosuggest with multiple words/terms so i can autocomplete multiple words?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also use `SpellCheckComponent` for better auto complete suggests.

See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester for details.

Edit:
Refer [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester) for solr5 and above

Comment: There is a limitation with Solr Suggester that it can retrieve only one field of the document from which it has derived the suggestion. So use it only if this limitation is not a hurdle in your use case.
Alternatively auto complete is implemented using Ngrams on a field and then searching on the same field.

Answer (score 12):

I just wrote a [blog post](http://blog.trifork.com/2012/02/15/different-ways-to-make-auto-suggestions-with-solr/) about different ways to make auto complete suggestions with Solr. It's basically a comparison of some different strategies, check it out, it might help.
If you want to make multiple terms suggestions, it turns out you should use, as already mentioned in the other answer you got, the `Suggester` component available in Solr starting from the 3.1 version. Since it has some limitations, you can also have a look at the [`ShingleFilterFactory`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory), which generates token NGrams. It creates combination of tokens as a single token, that's useful to suggest multiple words.

Comment: Can you update the link since it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out, it might help

http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/09/08/auto-suggest-from-popular-queries-using-edgengrams/

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the same task, finally got solved using TermsComponent with multiple fields. check this link.  http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/auto-completion-search-with-solr-using-NGrams-in-SOLR-td3998559i20.html